# Crypto API: Подписать данные сертификатом

Tags: криптография, c++

Есть Crypto API, есть сертификат, есть данные.
Необходимо получить подпись.

Можете написать последовательность действий, что зачем нужно вызывать, чтобы получить подпись? 
Ну допустим, как нибудь так:

```
m_certContext = CertCreateCertificateContext(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, (BYTE*)Сертификат, ДлинаСертификата);

...

CryptSignHash(hHash, AT_SIGNATURE, NULL, 0, pbSignature, &dwSigLen)
```

Свой код чуть попозже выложу, чтобы не замыливать глаза.

Answer (score 1):

Создавать хэш отдельно необязательно. Это может сделать CryptSignMessage. Примерный порядок действий

```
CRYPT_SIGN_MESSAGE_PARA param;// Параметры вызова

memset(&param, 0, sizeof(CRYPT_SIGN_MESSAGE_PARA)); // обязательно обнулить структуру
param.cbSize = sizeof(CRYPT_SIGN_MESSAGE_PARA); // Задать размер передаваемой структуры
param.dwMsgEncodingType = X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING; // В каком стандарте кодируется сообщение
param.pSigningCert = m_CertContext; // Устанавливаем сертификат открытого ключа, которым подпишем
// Остальные поля можно проигнорировать

DWORD       MessageSizeArray[1]; // Массив размеров подписываемых данных - за 1 сеанс можно подписать несколько - тут всего одно
const BYTE  *MessageArray[1]; // Массив указателей на данные

MessageArray[0] = msg; // Записываем указатель на блок подписываемых данных
MessageSizeArray[0] = (DWORD) sizeof(msg); // Записываем длину

BYTE    signed_mem[2048];   // Буфер для подписи. 2048 байтов должно хватить вроде, иначе реализуйте вариант с динамическим выделением памяти
DWORD   signed_mem_len = sizeof(signed_mem); // Размер буфера

// Собственно вызов функции подписывания
int ret;
ret = CryptSignMessage(
    &param, // Параметры
    TRUE,   // 
    1, // 1 подписываем
    MessageArray, // Сообщения
    MessageSizeArray, // Их длины
    signed_mem, // Указатель на память под подпись
    &signed_mem_len // Размер буфера
);
```

Comment: Я пробовал CryptSignMessage, но там подпись вместе с подписываемыми данными выдается, на сколько я понял. Хотя сейчас проверю еще разочек :)
Мерси.

Comment: второй параметр этой функции BOOL fDetachedSignature как раз и регулирует режим подписи. TRUE - значит подпись не будет содержать внутри данные, FALSE - будет

Comment: Вот если я делаю хэш, после этого делаю подписать хэш, то я получаю подпись, длиной 0х40, а если я подписываю CryptSignMessage с fDetachedSignature = TRUE, то длина 0х3ЕЕ. Какая-то она не очень детачт, или что-то нужно еще подкрутить в CRYPT_SIGN_MESSAGE_PARA.
Пришлось приписать param.HashAlgorithm = m_certContext->pCertInfo->SignatureAlgorithm; а то не создавалась подпись.

Comment: Распространенные алгоритмы ЭЦП формируют подпись, примерно равную по длине открытому ключу. 0x40 это 64 бита. Это что за подпись? 0x3EE = 1006 - примерно такая и должна быть, с обычным ключом длиной примерно 768 бит